# which layout i have to use for the below screenshot

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Actually i have to create a xml layout as similar to the below screenshot and i know there is two cardView in linear Layout of having weight

[image]

but can anyone check my code and guide me i on the correct path or not...
 **xml code:**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_top_bottom">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"

            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewbackground">

                <ImageView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/icon_btw_margin"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                  android:src="@drawable/service_provide_box_icon"
                  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                  android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                  android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_btw_padding" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    android:text="@string/testAddress"
                    android:textColor="@color/buttonbackground"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    />


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_top_bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_top_bottom"
            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewbackground">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/car_services_icon_one"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                     />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView><android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewbackground"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/icon_btw_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/car_services_icon_three"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"

            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewbackground">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/icon_btw_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/mechanics_available_icon"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_btw_padding" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/testMechanics"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    />


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_top_bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_top_bottom"
            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewbackground">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/car_services_iconfour"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="1sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView><android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewbackground"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/icon_btw_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/car_services_icon_two"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="1sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewbackground">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/icon_btw_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/mechanics_available_icon"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_btw_padding" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/testMechanics"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_btw_padding"
                    />


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no what are you making is way easy to make it by xml

Comment: fill_parent is also deprecated

Comment: oky i wil use the wrap_content instead of fil_parent can u tell me Easy Way

Comment: match parent should be replaced by fill_parent

Comment: also cardview should have on direct child only\

Comment: ohh sorry match_parent....

Comment: can i apply the layout_weight in Relative Layout because my left acrdView cover the75% portion

Comment: wieght are used with liniear layout.. i'm making a layout for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135026/discussion-between-techdigi-and-abhishek-singh).

Comment: check below my answer will helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XML  . may be its helpful for your work..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
android:weightSum="4">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#555555">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#124688"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/yourimage"
            android:text="500 west and avenue suite 5A"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/mechanic image"
            android:text="12 Mechanics availabe"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/watchimage"
            android:text="9:00AM to 11:00PM"/>
        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleX="0.5"
            android:scaleY="0.5"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#555555">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image3"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image4"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:drawableStart="@drawable/mechanics_available_icon"
how can i add a margin b/w the drawable and the Text VIew

Comment: @techDigi `android:drawablePadding="10dp"` set the space bwtween drawable and text

Comment: @AbhishekSingh your post is incomplete.

Comment: instead of copy you can edit .. I forgot to add `"@drawable/image4"/>` in last imageview tag